# What redirect URI should I use for an authorization call used in an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, electron

I have a basic Electron app doing nothing special, based on sample starter projects.

For my main window, I am loading in a URL as a GET request to an API endpoing

```
loginWindow.loadURL('https://apiwebsite.com/api/v1.0/authorize?secret_id=my_secret&redirect_uri=<???????>')
```

As a part of my GET request to this API endpoint I have to send a return URI. This actually works fine, in that I can get the API to return and load the URI that I specify. However I do not know what URI to specify to get this to come back to somewhere within my app where I can read the response and proceed.

I am used to web development but Electron is new to me. I do not follow how I can submit a return URI in this instance. What would be it be? Would it change for local development vs a packaged application?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202191/how-to-integrate-oauth-login-with-a-packaged-electron-app

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl this did lead me to the right answer. If you want to post an actual answer I can mark it as accepted, else I can do so.

Comment: So this is a new one on me. Is it really as simple as registering a custom protocol? Very convenient if so

Comment: Yes it does just work. Returns from the external URL to my custom protocol, where I can read the response, save it and now I'm just going to IPC my authentication to my render process, and begin to use m token to retrieve data.

Comment: @Twentyonehundred: Are you able to provide a code example for the custom protocol setup? I am following the electron registerFileProtocol example to accomplish the same thing you set out to do, but the website I'm trying to get the key from keeps saying:  "failed to launch [awesomeProtocol://example] because the scheme does not have a registered handler".

Comment: FYI I've added a question about this issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68590822/electron-custom-protocol-no-registered-handler-error

Answer (score 1):

**OAUTH FOR DESKTOP APPS**

[OAuth for desktop apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) recommends these 2 key behaviours:

- Login via the system browser so that your app never sees the user credential
- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) since your app is a public client

This typically leads to one of these solutions:

- Loopback based redirect URI such as http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback
- Private URI scheme based redirect URI such as **x-mycompany-desktopapp:/callback**

As you are finding, a standard HTTP based internet redirect URL will not work for a desktop app unless you use older (deprecated) web view solutions.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

It is tricky flow to implement, though my blog has a couple of Electron code samples that you can easily run from your local PC to see what both solutions look like:

- [Initial Desktop Code Sample, using the Loopback Solution](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/)
- [Final Desktop Code Sample, using the Private URI Scheme Solution](https://authguidance.com/2018/01/26/final-desktop-sample-overview/)

My samples are quite deep, but hopefully some of this is useful for your own solution ...

Comment: I'm trying to follow your Private URI Scheme Solution, but it's unclear to me how to specify the Private URI or link it to the app

Comment: Ah - have a look at the [interstitial web page](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/web/postlogin.html) which invokes the private URI scheme after login completion. This is not mandatory and you could use the private URI scheme directly in the desktop app's config file, but it prevents a leftover blank browser page.