# Electron custom protocol: 'no registered handler' error

Tags: oauth-2.0, electron, url-scheme

UPDATE: I have been able to get the website to redirect, but my electron app is not yet able to intercept that action. Is that possible in development? I have asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838012/does-electrons-registerhttpprotocol-work-in-development).

---

I'm trying to register a custom protocol with electron. I want it to be a redirect location that a website can use to provide an api key (like `myprotocol://example/payload=api-key`).

But when the website tries to redirect to my protocol it keeps saying: `failed to launch myprotocol://example/payload=key... because the scheme does not have a registered handler`.  What do I need to do to make this work?

I'm hoping to make this work in production and development.

I've seen discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202191/how-to-integrate-oauth-login-with-a-packaged-electron-app) and the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530295/what-redirect-uri-should-i-use-for-an-authorization-call-used-in-an-electron-app). Following along the docs from electron
[here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol), this is what I've tried:

main.js:

```
const { app, protocol } = require('electron')
    
app.whenReady().then(() => {
   protocol.registerFileProtocol('myprotocol', (request, callback) => {
      console.log('It worked! The website is sending this url: ' + request.url)
   }, (error) =>{
      if (error) console.log('Did not register the protocol')
   })
})
```

redirect uri provided to the website:

```
'myprotocol://example'
```

And I have been able to whitelist `myprotocol://example` at the website.

But, when the website tries to redirect to this protocol, my electron app does not register any activity, and the web inspector on the website shows the error: `failed to launch myprotocol://example/payload=key... because the scheme does not have a registered handler`.

I have additionally tried other methods, like `registerSchemesAsPrivileged` and `registerHttpProtocol`, without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please make sure that your capitalisation is correct. You're registering `myprotocol` but are actually redirecting to `myProtocol`. I assume that this is case-sensitive and thus the capital `P` matters.

Comment: capitalization for the protocol registered, redirected to, and whitelisted are the same.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53530726/1244884) help (at least for the protocol bit?)

Comment: Thanks. The answer you pointed to has some helpful ideas. It is focused on production, and I want something I can also work through in development. It also requires a few extra steps than the protocol API seems to require. So I am hoping there is a more direct solution.